# How to enable upside down orientation on flutter for iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-ios

I am trying to enable upside-down portrait mode on flutter app for ios. All orienations are enabled in the app:

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
```

All the orientation are also enabled on ios project settings through Xcode:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    </array>
```

For some reason on iOS upside-down portrait mode is not working.
Any ideas on what might be wrong is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)

> All iPadOS devices support the portraitUpsideDown orientation. It’s
> best practice to enable it for the iPad idiom. iOS devices without a
> Home button, such as iPhone 12, don’t support this orientation. You
> should disable it entirely for the iPhone idiom.

Do you test this feature on a proper ios device?

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: you are welcome :) @NazariiKahaniak